# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic3

im working on angular ionic 3 and when im click on a certain button im getting this error can anyone please help me determine this ?

**realestateproductdetails.ts**

```
if (localStorage.getItem('agentdetail')) {
      this.agentdetail = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('agentdetail'));
      for (let i = 0; i < this.agentdetail.branchDetails.length; i++) {
        this.branchCodeArray[i] = this.agentdetail.branchDetails[i].branchCode
      }
```

line 3rd starts from "for" is line 66
**error**

```
Runtime Error
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined


at new RealestateproductdetailsPage (realestateproductdetails.ts:66)
    at createClass (core.js:12491)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:12326)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:13784)
    at createRootView (core.js:13673)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.js:14381)
    at ComponentFactory_.create (core.js:11278)
    at ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create (core.js:4030)
    at NavControllerBase._viewInit (nav-controller-base.js:441)
    at c (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
    at NavControllerBase._fireError (nav-controller-base.js:223)
    at NavControllerBase._failed (nav-controller-base.js:216)
    at nav-controller-base.js:263
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
```

Comment: hey, attach your code here.

Comment: which part sir ?

Comment: Your error is in `realestateproductdetails.ts` at line `66`, where you try to access a property length from an undefined variable. In order to fix it, you would need to post the full code from that line

Comment: okay sir posting it

Comment: Please read this post. it might definitely help you to write a good question. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: updated the code , thank you i will read it

Comment: Looks like  `branchDetails` in `this.agentdetail.branchDetails` could be null... So you'd need to add an `if` statement there to avoid accessing `this.agentdetail.branchDetails.length` if `this.agentdetail.branchDetails` is null.

Comment: oh okay , thank you for the help sir

Answer (score 1):

```
if (localStorage.getItem('agentdetail')) {
      this.agentdetail = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('agentdetail'));
if (this.agentdetail && this.agentdetail.branchDetails && this.agentdetail.branchDetails.length > 0){
      for (let i = 0; i < this.agentdetail.branchDetails.length; i++) {
        this.branchCodeArray[i] = this.agentdetail.branchDetails[i].branchCode
      }
}
```

use like this it will work because **this.agentdetail.branchDetails** may be Empty

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this line  `for (let i = 0; i < this.agentdetail.branchDetails.length; i++)`.

When the loop is being executed, there is no value in the variable agentdetail. Most likely some code before this fails to assign any value to that variable. Debug the code to figure this out.

Alternatively, you can use the check mentioned by @sangar-lal in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same error while working on a news app, which fetches data from external API (NEWS API).
If you are working on same kind of thing,

you might have exceeded the API request limit.

To resolve this error just wait for 12 or 24 hours, your API requests get restored or upgrade to a paid plan.

Copy and paste the link of "Failed to load resource" in new tab to check your API status,
you may get:

{"status":"error","code":"rateLimited","message":"You have made too many requests recently. Developer accounts are limited to 100 requests over a 24 hour period (50 requests available every 12 hours). Please upgrade to a paid plan if you need more requests."}